# Equivalent sub-bases for the weak-star topology?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a vector field over $\mathbb C$ and $V^*$ be the dual space of $V$. Traditionally, authors define the weak$^*$-topology on $V^*$ as that which admits the collection of all sets of the form
\begin{align*}
N(f_0,x,\epsilon)=\{f\in V^*:|f(x)-f_0(x)|<\epsilon\},&&f_0\in V^*,x\in V,\epsilon>0\tag{1}
\end{align*}
as a sub-basis. I am currently reading online lecture notes on $C^*$-algebras (http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~m123s11/cstar.pdf), and it seems that the author asserts (see lemma 1.35) that the weak$^*$-topology is generated by the sub-basis consisting of the following collection of sets instead:
\begin{align*}
U(z,x,\epsilon)=\{f\in V^*:|f(x)-z|<\epsilon\},&&z\in\mathbb C,x\in V,\epsilon>0.\tag{2}
\end{align*}
It is not clear to me why (1) and (2) should be equal. Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: $x$ and $f_0$ are fixed so $f_0(x)$ is just an arbitrary complex number.

Comment: Right, but it seems to me like there are sets of the form (2) which may not be written as sets of the form (1) (unless for every $x\in V$ and $z\in\mathbb C$ there exists $f_0\in V^*$ such that $f_0(x)=z$). If this is the case, then we would have to show that the two topologies these sub-bases generate are equivalent?

Comment: $f_0$ is a linear functional. As long as $f_0\ne 0$, $f_0:V\to\mathbb{C}$ is onto, i.e., there's always an $x$ such that $f_0(x)=z$ for any given $z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to show that any set of the form (2) can be written in form (1). Let $x\in V$ and $z\in \mathbb C$. If $z=0$ then take $f_0$ to be the zero map. Thus, $f_0(x)=0=z$. If $z\ne0$, pick $f\in V^*$ so that $f(x)\ne0$, set $f_0=\frac{z}{f(x)}f$. It follows that $f_0(x)=z$ as desired.

Comment: One last detail, how do you know that for an arbitrary $x\neq0$ there exists $f\in V^*$ such that $f(x)\neq0$?

Comment: @RaisinBread If $V^*$ is the topological dual that follows from Hahn-Banach.

Comment: It seems like I really need to become more knowledgeable about basic functional analysis! Thanks for all the helpful comments.